# How to replace content of the file, if the file in the server is deleted?

Tags: java, file

I am placing the file "**Seq.properties**" in the SAP server location.

The file **Seq.properties** holds the count of 2 variable. Every time a call is made to the java  function, it increments the count of 2 variables and stores the file in the SAP server location.

The Code is as follow,

```
public final static String executeRegNo() {

    File file=new File("C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/Files/Seq.properties");
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    //1. If file Seq.properties doesnt exist, it first initializes TransNum to 0 and RegId to 1
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try
        {
            file.createNewFile();

            properties.setProperty("TransNum", "0");
            properties.setProperty("RegId", "1");
            properties.store(new FileOutputStream(file), null);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //2. If file Seq.properties exist, it reads the file Seq.properties and 
    //it increments TransNum to prev_value+1 and RegId remains the same 1
    try
    {

        properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String transId = properties.getProperty("TransNum");
    String RegisId = properties.getProperty("RegId");

    properties.setProperty("TransNum", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(transId) + 1));
    properties.setProperty("RegId", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(RegisId)));

    //3. the incremented value is stored in the Seq.properties file
    try
    {

        properties.store(new FileOutputStream(file), null);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String RId = properties.getProperty("RegId");
    String TId = properties.getProperty("TransNum");
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
    String R = String.valueOf(df.format(Integer.parseInt(RId)));
    DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("0000");
    String T = String.valueOf(df1.format(Integer.parseInt(TId)));
    return R + T;
}
```

Suppose in case due to system failure, if the file **Seq.properties** gets deleted, how to replace the content of that file?

Kindly provide your valuable inputs, as this is critical requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @AndyTurner- code is posted

Comment: By **replace the content of that file** do you mean you want to **recover** the contents? Or you just want to create the file again with values you have?

Comment: @Codebender- Due to system crash if file Seq.properties is deleted, then i want to create a file in the same location with the previous value. Suppose if Trans_no = 99 and reg_id=1 now if system crashes, a file should be generated and should hold the value Trans_no = 99 and reg_id=1

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion is to **store the content** of variable in **database** and whenever u are retrieving the **Seq.properties** file, **load the value from the database**.
If the file is not present,it creates new file with previous value

Comment: Thanks - But the cost is more to avail database. This is real time scenario

Comment: Ok.Then its like store the file in local and as well as server.Once when u are trying to retrive the value from file,and if file is not present copy the file from server and get the value from it.

Comment: If you have so much load that the database query cost is of any importance, a file based solution will not work. You will end up locking the file or multiple clients will write to it at the same time. A database is the proper answer to your problem.